# scala group by on a Cassandra table column of list type

Tags: scala, list, cassandra

I would like apply group by on top_places ( Which is list).

```
tenant_id | device_id | top_places
-----------+-----------+------------
        T1 |        D2 | ['F', 'D']
        T1 |        D3 | ['F', 'D']
        T1 |        D4 | ['G', 'D']
        T1 |        D5 | ['G', 'Q']
        T1 |        D6 | ['A', 'F']
```

This is the result i get when i run following scala snippet 
`val results = rows.groupBy("top_places").agg(Map("*"->"count")).withColumnRenamed("COUNT(1)","Total").select("top_places","Total"    ).orderBy("Total");`

```
[List(G, D),1]                                                                  
[List(A, F),1]
[List(G, Q),1]
[List(F, D),2]
```

What i need is as follows, How do i get the same?

```
[A,1]
[G,2]
[F,2]
[D,2]
[Q,1]
```

Comment: Shouldn't D and F be 3?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.  Just need to first flatten `top_places` with `explode()`:

```
val rows = Seq(
  ("T1", "D2", Seq("F", "D")),
  ("T1", "D3", Seq("F", "D")),
  ("T1", "D4", Seq("G", "D")),
  ("T1", "D5", Seq("G", "Q")),
  ("T1", "D6", Seq("A", "F"))
).toDF("tenant_id", "device_id", "top_places")

rows.withColumn("top_place", explode($"top_places")).
  groupBy("top_place").agg(Map("*"->"count")).
  withColumnRenamed("COUNT(1)","Total").
  orderBy("total").
  show

// +---------+-----+                                                               
// |top_place|total|
// +---------+-----+
// |        Q|    1|
// |        A|    1|
// |        G|    2|
// |        F|    3|
// |        D|    3|
// +---------+-----+
```

You can also replace `agg(Map("*"->"count"))` with `agg(count())`:

```
rows.withColumn("top_place", explode($"top_places")).
  groupBy("top_place").agg(count("top_place").as("total")).
  orderBy("total")
```